# Using Infinity Symbol in App's Name

Tags: iphone

I intend to use the infinity symbol (∞) in my App's name. I have registered the app name on itune-connect. every thing fine ! But when I config the App's name in my project, some time I got an error when Debugger try to install the App on my device.

I wonder that can I use that symbol in my app's name, does it make my customer have the problem when installing app on device or .... ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: KISS. dont try to be so clever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the BundleID does not have the infinity symbol in it.

From Apple: a CFBundleIdentifier is similar to a UTI, it is not actually a UTI, as the allowed character set is more restricted.

Answer (score 1):

I am Thai and I can even use Thai language as app name so it would be fine. I guess you might have changed the Product Name in build settings, instead of change the name in plist file. I think you should use English product name in build settings and dont use ${PRODUCT_NAME} in your plist file.

Comment: Your advice is very useful, my problem solved !
Just use normal name in Build Tab property, and change the Bundle Display Name in plist to whatever you want ^^!